# How to calculate precision, recall in multiclass classification problem after each epoch during training?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, resnet, precision-recall

I am using Tensorflow 1.15.0 and keras 2.3.1.I'm trying to calculate precision and recall of six class classification problem of each epoch for my training data and validation data during training. 
I can use the classification_report but it works only after training has completed.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_pred = final.predict(X_test)
y_indx = np.argmax(y_test_new, axis = 1)
pred_indx = np.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)
print(classification_report(y_indx, pred_indx))
```

The result for network ResNet154 is like below and my dataset is balanced.

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.00      0.00      0.00    172482
       1       0.00      0.00      0.00    172482
       2       0.00      0.00      0.00    172482
       3       0.00      0.00      0.00    172482
       4       0.00      0.00      0.00    172482
       5       0.17      1.00      0.29    172482


accuracy                           0.17   1034892
macro avg       0.03      0.17      0.05   1034892
weighted avg       0.03      0.17      0.05   1034892
```

I just want to check precision and recall and f1-score of my training data by using callbacks to be sure that whether or not it is overfitting of network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a specific callback in order to do this.

One solution to your problem is available in the following article: https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2.

The article above mentions how to calculate your desired metrics at the end of each epoch.

Otherwise, you can define a custom callback in which you have the access to your validation set; in the `on_epoch_end()`, you get the number of `TP`, `TN`, `FN`, `FP`, with which you can calculate all the metrics that you want.

Also, you can check this example written here (work on TensorFlow `2.X` versions, `>=2.1`) : [How to get other metrics in Tensorflow 2.0 (not only accuracy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616842/how-to-get-other-metrics-in-tensorflow-2-0-not-only-accuracy/60617333#60617333)